# Why my click not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I just try this code:

```
$("#test").ready(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        alert('clicked!');
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8bfqw/

Why it's still alert when I click outside of the div?

Comment: Here's a hint: http://jsfiddle.net/8BFQW/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your selector `$(#test)` is actually `$(document)` since from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the
>   current document

Whatever you pass inside the selector, it'll be omitted and work on the current document. A shorthand version of `$(document).ready(function(){})` is `$(function(){});` so you want:

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        alert('clicked!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#test").ready(function() {
    $("#test").click(function() {
        alert('clicked!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").ready(function() {
    $("#test").click(function() {
         alert('clicked!');
     });
});
```

You have to set the click-function to the Test-object, instead of the whole document $(this).